# How to change the button's text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have the following code to set the text of the button through javascript code , but it does not work it remains same the text remains same.

```
function showFilterItem() {
    if (filterstatus == 0) {
        filterstatus = 1;
        $find('<%=FileAdminRadGrid.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().showFilterItem();
        document.getElementById("ShowButton").innerHTML = "Hide Filter";
    }
    else {
        filterstatus = 0;
        $find('<%=FileAdminRadGrid.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().hideFilterItem();
        document.getElementById("ShowButton").innerHTML = "Show filter";
    }
}
```

And my html button code is

```
  <input  class="button black" id="ShowButton" type="button" runat="server"  value="Show Filter" onclick="showFilterItem()" />
```

Comment: [Changing button **text** and not **value** using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679813/how-to-change-button-text-or-link-text-in-javascript)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

If the `HTMLElement` is `input[type='button']`, `input[type='submit']`, etc.

```
<input id="ShowButton" type="button" value="Show">
<input id="ShowButton" type="submit" value="Show">
```

change it using this code:

```
document.querySelector('#ShowButton').value = 'Hide';
```

If, the `HTMLElement` is `button[type='button']`, `button[type='submit']`, etc:

```
<button id="ShowButton" type="button">Show</button>
<button id="ShowButton" type="submit">Show</button>
```

change it using any of these methods,

```
document.querySelector('#ShowButton').innerHTML = 'Hide';
document.querySelector('#ShowButton').innerText = 'Hide';
document.querySelector('#ShowButton').textContent = 'Hide';
```

Please note that

- `input` is an [empty tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element) and **cannot have** `innerHTML`, `innerText` or `textContent`
- `button` is a *container tag* and **can have** `innerHTML`, `innerText` or `textContent`

---

#### Ignore this answer if you ain't using asp.net-web-forms, asp.net-ajax and rad-grid

You must use `value` instead of <strike>`innerHTML`</strike>.

Try this.

```
document.getElementById("ShowButton").value= "Hide Filter";
```

And since you are running the button at `server` the ID may get mangled in the framework. I so, try

```
document.getElementById('<%=ShowButton.ClientID %>').value= "Hide Filter";
```

Another better way to do this is like this.

On markup, change your onclick attribute like this. `onclick="showFilterItem(this)"`

Now use it like this

```
function showFilterItem(objButton) {
    if (filterstatus == 0) {
        filterstatus = 1;
        $find('<%=FileAdminRadGrid.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().showFilterItem();
        objButton.value = "Hide Filter";
    }
    else {
        filterstatus = 0;
        $find('<%=FileAdminRadGrid.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().hideFilterItem();
        objButton.value = "Show filter";
    }
}
```

Comment: was looking for this:  document.getElementById("ShowButton").value= "Hide Filter";  Thanks!

Comment: This answer is outdated and now incorrect, it should be removed.

Comment: @Maitreya The OP is using `<input type="button">` so `element.value` is the correct way to change the button's displayed text. `innerText`, `innerHTML`, and `textContent` would be used if you are using `<button></button>` since it has a opening and closing tag.

Comment: This answer is **very helpful**! I was looking for `document.querySelector('#ShowButton').value = 'Hide';` for a long time ....

Answer (score 75):

innerText is the current correct answer for this. The other answers are outdated and incorrect.

```
document.getElementById('ShowButton').innerText = 'Show filter';
```

innerHTML also works, and can be used to insert HTML.

Comment: You are correct.  Thanks for the help.  .value did not work in Chrome but .innerText did.

Comment: This isn't the correct answer for the OP's specific issue. `<input>` does not have an `innerText`

Answer (score 24):

I know this question has been answered but I also see there is another way missing which I would like to cover it.There are multiple ways to achieve this.

**1- innerHTML**

```
document.getElementById("ShowButton").innerHTML = 'Show Filter';
```

You can insert HTML into this. But the disadvantage of this method is, it has **cross site security attacks**. So for adding text, its better to avoid this for security reasons.

**2- innerText**

```
document.getElementById("ShowButton").innerText = 'Show Filter';
```

This will also achieve the result but its heavy under the hood as it **requires some layout system information**, due to which the performance decreases. Unlike innerHTML, you cannot insert the HTML tags with this.
[Check Performance Here](https://kellegous.com/j/2013/02/27/innertext-vs-textcontent/)

**3- textContent**

```
document.getElementById("ShowButton").textContent = 'Show Filter';
```

This will also achieve the same result but it doesn't have security issues like innerHTML as it doesn't parse HTML like innerText. Besides, it is also light due to which performance increases.

So if a text has to be added like above, then its better to use textContent.

Comment: My button was like this: <button class="ts-button ts-padding-large ts-light-grey" style="margin-top:32px" onclick="toggleGalleries(this)">MORE GALLERIES</button> So using value didn't work but using textContent did the trick. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

Another solution could be using jquery button selector inside the if else statement  $("#buttonId").text("your text");

```
function showFilterItem() {
if (filterstatus == 0) {
    filterstatus = 1;
    $find('<%=FileAdminRadGrid.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().showFilterItem();
    $("#ShowButton").text("Hide Filter");
}
else {
    filterstatus = 0;
    $find('<%=FileAdminRadGrid.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().hideFilterItem();
     $("#ShowButton").text("Show Filter");
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle `filterstatus` value like this

```
filterstatus ^= 1;
```

So your function looks like

```
function showFilterItem(objButton) {
if (filterstatus == 0) {
    $find('<%=FileAdminRadGrid.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().showFilterItem();
    objButton.value = "Hide Filter";
}
else {
    $find('<%=FileAdminRadGrid.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().hideFilterItem();
    objButton.value = "Show filter";
}
  filterstatus ^= 1;    
}
```