# How to change button text or link text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have this HTML button:

```
<button id="myButton" onClick="lock(); toggleText(this.id);">Lock</button>
```

And this is my `toggleText` JavaScript function:

```
function toggleText(button_id) 
{
   if (document.getElementById('button_id').text == "Lock") 
   {
       document.getElementById('button_id').text = "Unlock";
   }
   else 
   {
     document.getElementById('button_id').text = "Lock";
   }
}
```

As far as I know, button text (`<button id="myButton">Lock</button>`) is just like any link text
 (`<a href="#">Lock</a>`). So the fact that it's a button doesn't matter. However, I can't access the button text and change it.

I tried `('button_id')`, `(button_id)`, `== "Lock"`, `== 'Lock'`, but nothing works.

**How can I access and change a button text (not value) or a link text?**

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Change `.text` to `.textContent` to get/set the text content.

Or since you're dealing with a single text node, use `.firstChild.data` in the same manner.

Also, let's make sensible use of a variable, and enjoy some code reduction and eliminate redundant DOM selection by caching the result of `getElementById`.

```
function toggleText(button_id) 
{
   var el = document.getElementById(button_id);
   if (el.firstChild.data == "Lock") 
   {
       el.firstChild.data = "Unlock";
   }
   else 
   {
     el.firstChild.data = "Lock";
   }
}
```

Or even more compact like this:

```
function toggleText(button_id)  {
   var text = document.getElementById(button_id).firstChild;
   text.data = text.data == "Lock" ? "Unlock" : "Lock";
}
```

Comment: Whats the advantages of using the `.firstChild.data`?

Comment: @tempy: It's very fast, and cross browser compatible. People use `.innerHTML` because the DOM standard `.textContent` isn't implemented in some browsers, especially older IE. But `.innerHTML` is an HTML parser, so it's a bit of a hackish way to go. Working directly with the text node is very clean.

Answer (score 29):

```
document.getElementById(button_id).innerHTML = 'Lock';
```

Comment: It's not working. Maybe I have another mistake in my function?

Comment: Don't put quotes around the `button_id`.

Comment: Is there any difference between `.innerHTML` and `.textContent` as suggested by user1689607? They both work.

Comment: `innerHTML` lets you add HTML tags while `textContent` will only work with text nodes AFAIK

Comment: @Callum McLean: Nice catch, just noticed what you meant, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use:

`document.getElementById(button_id).innerText = 'Your text here';`

If you want to use HTML formatting, use the `innerHTML` property instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Quote. and use innerText instead of text

```
function toggleText(button_id) 
{                      //-----\/ 'button_id' - > button_id
   if (document.getElementById(button_id).innerText == "Lock") 
   {
       document.getElementById(button_id).innerText = "Unlock";
   }
   else 
   {
     document.getElementById(button_id).innerText = "Lock";
   }
}
```

Comment: This + changing the `.text` solved my problem. So only removing the quote isn't enough. I also mentioned it in my question.