# Changing contents of button when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason I'm stumped trying to change the contents of a button when clicked. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Exam 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
<p>
    <button id="button">Start</button>
    </p></div>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <div><p>
        <img src="turret-portal.jpg" height="150" width="100"/>
        </p></div>

    <script>
var button=document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function() {
     button.value = "test";
};    
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I feel like I am fundamentally misunderstanding something.

Thanks for your help

edit:

This also doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Exam 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
<p>
    <button id="button">Start</button>
    </p></div>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <div><p>
        <img src="turret-portal.jpg" id="pic" height="150" width="100"/>
        </p></div>

    <script>
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
     document.getElementById("button").innerText = "test";
};    
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So: what happens?  what do you expect should happen?  (And it looks like you're setting button.value ... I would expect you'd want to do something like var resultP = document.getElementById("result"); and then set e.g. the innerHtml of resultP to be "test")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your javascript to this:

```
var button=document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function() {
    button.innerHTML = "test";
};
```

You would use `.value` if it was `<input type=button/>`

Here is working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q0g8c78q/

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to get the button to change back and forth between values. Here is my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/q0g8c78q/1/

Comment: I can't get the boolean variable in the javascript to go back an forth like I want

Comment: You have `innerHtml` instead of `innerHTML` (notice the capital HTML). Here is a working fiddle of what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/32gfodkr/1/

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to change the value attribute. You want to modify the text content.

So you can replace `button.value = "test";` with `button.innerText = "test";`.

Also, you can change the data for the text node that's inside your `button` element, as stated in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12679841/58128).

Comment: innerHTML is what you meant since innerText doesn't work

Comment: @CarlGanz `innerText` should work as well. Here is a working bin http://jsbin.com/xugisetewu/edit?html,output . You should use `innerText` if you are only inserting text content such as `test`. And you might user `innerHTML` if you want to set HTML as the content, such as `<b>test</b>`.