# How can I modify nested text within an ID element using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to change the text within my button and I just wondering is it possible for me to change it?

```
<div id="something">

<button class="someClass">This I wanna change</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change button text or link text in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679813/how-to-change-button-text-or-link-text-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Find class inside div and change your text like below.

```js
$('#something').find('.someClass').text('I am changed');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="something">
  <button class="someClass">This I wanna change</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".someClass").text('New Text')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="something">

<button class="someClass">This I wanna change</button>

</div>
```