# Simple Script For On/Off Switch Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

The expected result for my code below should give me a small button that switches in between display "On" and "Off" when clicked. For the sake of simplicity I narrowed down the code. Any ideas on why this isn't working?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button id="state" onclick="switch()">On</button>
        <script>
            function switch() {
                if (document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = "On") {
                    document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = "Off";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = "On";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: also dont think that you should name your functions after Javascript keywords..

Comment: Also, if you are going to use an inline binding like that, you might as well change it to `onclick="switch(this)"` to pass in the button so your method doesn't have to look it up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change button text or link text in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679813/how-to-change-button-text-or-link-text-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used reserved name 'switch' and forgot to use '===' instead '='.

```
<script>
            function switchButton() {
              console.log(document.getElementById("state").innerHTML);
                if (document.getElementById("state").innerHTML === "On") {
                    document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = "Off";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = "On";
                }
            }
        </script>  
  <button id="state" onclick="switchButton()">On</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you make it easier?

```js
const switchOnOff = () => {
document.getElementById("state").innerHTML == "On" ? document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = "Off" : document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = "On"
}
```

```html
<button id="state" onclick="switchOnOff()">On</button>
```

Comment: `switchOnOff = () => {
  document.getElementById("state").innerHTML=
    document.getElementById("state").innerHTML == "On" ? "Off" : "On";
}`

Answer (score 2):

there is two issues

first the name of the function is reserved name , you can not name function 'switch' as it is reserved

second things you missed an = in the if statement

try this

```
 function switchit() {
            if (document.getElementById("state").innerHTML == "On") {
                document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = "Off";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = "On";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't test in `if` = you've set...

```js
function switchOnOff() {
  if (document.getElementById("state").innerHTML == "On") {
    document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = "Off";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = "On";
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="state" onclick="switchOnOff()">On</button>
</body>
```

And `switch` is a reserved keyword - I've changed to `switchOnOff`.

---

Here's another solution with reference to caller:

```js
function switchOnOff(element) {
  if (element.innerHTML == "On") {
    element.innerHTML = "Off";
  } else {
    element.innerHTML = "On";
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="state" onclick="switchOnOff(this)">On</button>
</body>
```